# BigQuery from VM Instance accessing GHCN Daily data causing hiccups

Tags: google-bigquery

```
    $queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery("
                SELECT 
                    date, 
                    (value/10)+273 as temperature
                FROM 
                    [bigquery-public-data:ghcn_d.ghcnd_$year]
                WHERE 
                    id = '{$station['id']}' AND 
                    element LIKE '%$element%'
                ORDER BY 
                    date, 
                    temperature"
            );
```

I am calling this query and iterating over the years for each station. It gets through 1 or 2 stations and then I get a

killed

on my output and the process is halted...

Is it possible that the queries are not closing? I am looking for a close query, but it appears that it should close itself?

Any Ideas?

Comment: just wondering, have you checked your memory to see how it's being used? is it full?

Comment: I will check that.. Thanks.

Comment: +Will -- Brilliant answer.

In my briliance, I did 5 things at the same time and pushed the memory over the limit. Making five 80,000 pixel wide images at the same time was a little much for the f1-Micro I am running on.